# char*a[2]={"bylochka","pirozhok"}; char *b=a; -- Почему не работает?

Tags: c, указатели

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    char*a[2]={"bylochka","pirozhok"};
    char *b=a;
    printf ("%s", *b);
    printf ("%s", *a);
    return 0 ;
}
```

Почему в строчке `char *b=a;` компилятор выдает предупреждение? Я же присваиваю адрес нулевого указателя. `printf ("%s", *a);` и `printf ("%s", *a);` же абсолютно одинаковы, но `printf ("%s", *b);` не работает, а `printf ("%s", *a);` работает и выводит надпись "bylochka", почему `printf ("%s", *b);` не работает я могу понять, то есть `char *b=a;` присваивает адрес нулевого указателя, но в этом указателе хранится адрес нулевого элемента строки "bylochka", т.к строка это тот же массив, а я пытаюсь вывести адрес с помощью индентификатора %s. Так почему тогда `printf ("%s", *a);` выводит строку без проблем? Может я что-то неправильно понял? Буду очень благодарен за объяснения)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Язык С является строго типизированным языком программирования. Выражение `a` в вашем контексте имеет тип `char **`. А вы его пытаетесь силой засунуть в переменную типа `char *`. Это совсем разные типы.

Также, выражение `a` в вашем контексте указывает на начало массива `a`. Этот массив `a` не является строкой. Почему вы пытаетесь использовать его, как строку?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96407/discussion-on-answer-by-ant-chara2bylochka-pirozhok-char-ba-).

Answer (score 5):

Давайте просто заменим тип `char*` на `int`... Итак, у вас есть массив

```
int a[2];
```

Теперь мы пишем

```
int b = a;
```

Вас удивляет, что указатель на первый элемент (`a`) не присваивается значению?
Тогда почему вас удивляет, что в

```
char* a[2];
```

вы не можете присвоить

```
char* b = a;
```

? Ведь `a` точно так же указатель на первый элемент - **на указатель**, который указывает на "былочку"... Обратите внимание - `a` - *указатель на указатель*, в то время как `b` - просто *указатель*.

Comment: Да хоть 300 указателей,  я же пытаюсь присвоить адрес первого указателя. Не могу понять

Comment: Что именно? Ну, попробуйте явно привести тип - `b = (char*)a;`, и убедитесь, что никакой bylochka там нет... Если же вас просто удивляет, что нельзя присваивать одну другой переменные разных типов - ну, язык такой, строго типизированный. Не разрешает крокодилам присваивать попугаев...